Adding graphics to a motorbike helmet Model
I need to add a set of 7-8 seperate PNG graphics to a motorbike helmet model. Never used UV maps before and texture paint etc and have spent hours wathcing many tutorials about how best to achive but come accross many problems.
I woudl like to ask whats the best approach as I need to have a lot of freedom to scale and place the images alongsie each other.
The total curve of the helmet is making very difficult and have notcied theres a few approaches but cant get any working so wanted to go back to the drawing board and see if anyone has any good suggesteions for the best approach.
Using Blender 4.0 so alot of the tutorials etc certian buttons moved and hard to follow.
Any help very much appreciated.
Thanks
P.S - Any good upto date tutorials or info links appreciated.

Hello, Hans. This really is (probably) just the art of UV unwrapping. This is kind of unanswerable in our format.. we can't  do a completely generalized tutorial on the subject. What you could do, to fit in, on BSE, is, say,  present us with one of the graphics, and where you want it to go on the helmet (no need to share the whole thing if you don't want to).. and what you've tried already that doesn't work. Then we have a specific problem we can solve, which will probably help you work the others out.

please pack your images and share your file so that we can give a try?

You can create a second UV map for the logo, scale up the faces where the logo is supposed to be, scale down the rest, use an Input > UV Map node, select this second UV map, and mix the basic material of your helmet with the logo, plug the Alpha output of the logo Image Texture into the factor of the Mix Shader so that you can see the basic material:

